# Grail data-migration-plugin

Tags: grails, data-migration

I followed the instruction from this link
http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/3.0.x/index.html#introduction

First I added the lines needed in application.yml:

```
buildscript {
   dependencies {
      ...
      classpath 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.0.0'
   }
}

dependencies {
   ...
     compile 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.0.0'
     compile 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.5.3'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir 'grails-app/migrations'
        }
    }
}
```

Then I run "grails dbm-generate-changelog changelog.groovy" and after that: "grails dbm-changelog-sync"
Then I added a view to the changelog.groovy file:

```
databaseChangeLog = {

    changeSet(author: "xxx (generated)", id: "1490002519504-99", contexts: 'Test') {
        createView("""
            SELECT     dbo.Client.ClientNo, dbo.Client.ClientName
            FROM       dbo.Client INNER JOIN
                       dbo.ClientRole ON dbo.Client.ClientNo = dbo.ClientRole.ClientNo AND dbo.ClientRole.RoleType = 2
                       """, viewName: 'dbo.vw_supplier'
                       )
    }

    changeSet(author: "xxx (generated)", id: "1490002519504-1", contexts: 'Test') {
        createTable(tableName: "orders") {
            column(autoIncrement: "true", name: "id", type: "bigint") {
                constraints(primaryKey: "true", primaryKeyName: "PK__orders__3213E83F6FCA6F65")
            }
```

I added the following lines into application.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartFilename = 'changelog.groovy'
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart = true
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartContexts = ['Test']
```

After some tries I commented the last line to not use "contexts" but it didn't changed anything.

I also changed in bootstrap for development create-drop to none.
I removed all tables from the database and  run "grails dbm-update"
It then creates all tables but not the view I added to the "changelog.groovy".
The tables was all created without any column.
I also received a strange message:

```
"INFO 2017-03-20 12:54: liquibase: Can not use class org.grails.plugins.databasemigration.liquibase.GormDatabase as a Liquibase service because it does not have a no-argument constructor"


buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.11.6"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:6.0.4"
        classpath 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

My project now totally stalled.

Comment: Why did you add `grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartContexts = ['Test']` do you want the migration to run on Test context only?

Comment: No dynamo, this word 'Test' could have been any word, it is just to select which changeSet to be updated at start. If you look at the changeSet you can see that it is marked with 'Test' but there is other tables in different changeSets that I don't want to be updated at start.

Comment: The code for createView was copied from a tutorial on the net so I was fooled by that. Thank's to you dynamo I have jumped over this step. We'll see if I ever reach the top ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your syntax for create view is not correct add `selectQuery=` infront of the string to create view.

```
createView(selectQuery="""
    SELECT     dbo.Client.ClientNo, dbo.Client.ClientName
    FROM       dbo.Client INNER JOIN
               dbo.ClientRole ON dbo.Client.ClientNo = dbo.ClientRole.ClientNo AND dbo.ClientRole.RoleType = 2
               """, viewName: 'dbo.vw_supplier'
               )
```